# Vuforia on Flutter says "engine init error"

Tags: unity-game-engine, flutter, vuforia

Here iam working with Unity+Vuforia and Flutter

While i play and build the unity app in the unity with vuforia, it works fine

But after i export it to my flutter project using [this method](https://github.com/snowballdigital/flutter-unity-view-widget), when i press the button from my app to open the unity scene, it says : [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OfiX.jpg)

Any suggestions?

Regards, Slim

Answer (score 0):

The package is corrupted, you can see the many problems in the issues section. Unity runs better on flutter using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity) package. You can see a full integration example we created in [this repo](https://github.com/echoARxyz/Flutter-Unity-ARFoundation-echoAR-example).

Comment: Somehow, I'll try this, and will be reporting if i encounter any issue, thanks mate for the assistant

Comment: It's seems i forget to add the isArScene : true inside the UnityWidget, and that fix my problem